# why save.image() not = to output in folder? R

Tags: r, save, output

I am trying to save and environment in R. The most important value is a List of about 30MB data. The .RDta file that outputs in my folder however is a mere 6,252KB.

I tried both the Save button and the `save.image` function. 
Not sure what is the issue.

Comment: Did you read the data back in to another/different R session and it wasn't correct? If it was highly compressible data you'll get a good compression ratio. Also, I realize you're using the shortcut to save your workspace, but why not just save out what's really needed with just `save()` or `saveRDS()`?

Comment: `save.image` uses compression by default. Try what size you get without compression.

Comment: Looks like save() does the job and can retrieve with load(), I usually saved just the env. the compression is pretty impressive from a list of 28MB to a file of 1260KB, not sure how its possible. Thanks guys